# Press home button to upgrade (broken home button)

Tags: iphone

I googled everything & everywhere but couldn't find an answer.

I have an iPhone 7 Plus stuck at press home to upgrade screen; the home button is broken. I tried pressing power + volume down. Then tried connecting iTunes: it says enter passcode on phone to connect. Latest iOS.

Advise a solution please.

If this button is repairable or not?

Comment: Broken as in physically in pieces or just unreaponsive when pressing it? I had an iPad with a stuck home button and had to (funny enough) tilt it upside down, so that the home button was at the top and the camera at the bottom, only then was it able to register the click. Try it out or define "broken".